# IntelliJ Idea failed with 'Git Pull Failed. Permission denied (publickey).' during the pulling

Tags: git, intellij-idea, ssh, proxy, gitlab

Firstly, my machine's working under proxy (via openVPN). I have a project which was cloned from GitLab repo. When i try to work with git via terminal it works fine, but when i try to work via IntelliJ Idea it fails with error 'Permission denied (publickey)'. 'SSH executable' setting in IDE set to 'Native'. SSH-key was added to my GitLab's profile. It's weird for me, cause git works fine via terminal. Maybe root cause is in my proxy settings or in IDE's settings?

Answer (score 2):

The error looks like wrong ssh key is used to access the repository, so likely it is not related to proxy settings. However, if a proxy is configured in IDEA, try disabling it to make sure.

Other possible reasons are:

- Different git client is used in the IDE (not the same as in shell)
- On Windows, you are using GitBash with some specific .ssh/config that
  works only in GutBash and not in windows command prompt
- IDE helper that handles password prompts fails for some reasons
- Something else?

Check IDE logs fro more details.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. My ssh keys were generated by Git Bash. I have only one key-pair in my .ssh folder and public key was addded to my GitLab. Git works fine from windows terminal (not only from Git Bash). I have checked my IDE's logs and found these lines:                                                                                       
 2019-02-28 12:17:54,803 [1620740]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - git@my.gitlab.repo Permission denied (publickey). 
2019-02-28 12:17:54,805 [1620742]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: UPD: There are no any passwords for my ssh keys

Comment: UUPD: 'Path to Git executable' setting in my IDEA refers to actual git.

Answer (score 0):

I used Pycharm (also from JetBrains same as IntelliJ IDEA) and seen a similar issue in pycharm.
Native mode should use your system setting, right? Pycharm named it 'Auto-detect proxy setting', this mode is not worked for me, then I use manual mode to fill my proxy setting.
It works well now.

Hope it's helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me. I've found the setting and configured it manually, but it did't help me - the same error

Comment: Or you can configure your private key path in setting->SSH